# Pixel location through MATLAB

Tags: image, image-processing, matlab

I am working on a project where I have to find a certain object on a platform using an attached camera through [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB). I thought about using the platform as a grid, but I've been told that using the pixels of the camera, I might be able to get that position precisely by clicking on the camera window/screen and choosing a certain pixel (where the objects are going to show on the camera window/screen).

Is there a way to calculate the location of the object (clicked pixel) or is there any possible way I could do that?

Comment: Using the known size of the platform and the pixels dimensions of the camera's CCD, couldn't you compute a scale factor to convert pixel position to distance?

Comment: This is how it's done in OpenCV: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/calib3d_camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=calibrate#CalibrateCamera2 . There's a matlab package that allows you to use opencv I think.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the ginput(...) function in MATLAB, like this:

```
% Load some image:
data = imread('fishy 01.jpg');

% display the image:
figure(88);
clf;
h = imagesc(data);
axis image

% Get a value from the screen:
[x, y] = ginput(1);

msgbox(['You want pixel: ' num2str(round([x,y]))]);
```

This will give you the location of the pixel in the current axis. Alternately you, could use the figure callback [WindowButtonUpFcn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html#WindowButtonUpFcn) to get the current mouse position in the figure then translate that over to the axis you want it relative to, then scale to the current axis xlim and ylim. But ginput(1) will be much easier.

[image: Example Run]

Comment: why did you use imagesc just to display the image? And If i want to use imshow, is there anyway to display axis (with values) like your example? (+1 anyway)

Comment: @yes123 I just use imagesc by habit, and works about the same as imshow when the data types are correct and within the right range----otherwise it scales. You could use `h=imshow(data);axis on;` instead.

Comment: @yes123 the `axis on` part should turn the labels on. If you still don't see them you might try `set(gca,'xtickMode', 'auto', 'ytickmode', 'auto')` or otherwise playing with axis properties like xtick, xticklabel, and xtickmode.