# extracting x,y co-ordinates from an image

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pixel location through matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251267/pixel-location-through-matlab)

hello all,
i want to know that how I can extract co-odinates from a scanned image (with the help of mouse, as I click and it will generate the co-ordinates of that point). Plz help. I am need for that. (which can give the co-ordinates in decimals and also take the size of the image automatically (if possible))

Comment: In Matlab, images are represented as 2D (or 3D) arrays.  So the size of the image is the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command imshow('filename') to bring up a figure with your image showing.

Then hit the "Data Cursor" button (it has a plus sign and a little yellow box on it). Clicking anywhere on the image will bring up the pixel's coordinates and RGB values.

Information such as the image's size can be found with imtool('filename') followed by Tools>Image Information.

Hope that helps.